# Will this result in two full table scans?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
SELECT P_CODE, P_PRICE
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE P_PRICE >= (SELECT AVG(P_PRICE) FROM PRODUCT);
```

Will this query (under mysql) result in two full table scans (from disk) or will the optimizer understand that it's faster too (if there is enough RAM to hold the result set) only do one full table scan? The table has no indexes.

Is it possible to read (somehow) this information from output of the EXPLAIN command in mysql?

Comment: well, tell us how could you know the average of the values in the table without scanning them. Doesn't it look impossible?

Comment: @Shinratensei You do one table scan to copy the table into an in-memory table, then do operations on that, presumably

Comment: @Shinratensei the way Caleth summarized it. This was my assumption, but it might not work that way.

Comment: @Caleth Operations "in-memory" still require reading and processing the data for said operations. The fact that disk IO is eliminated offers a performance benefit, but it does not change the fact that a table scan is still required.

Comment: Exactly. In this case, a performance improvement doesn't mean that you're reading less data, it means that it's allocated somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

The question is flawed based on a misunderstanding of what a *table scan* actually is:

- A *table scan* iterates over all rows in the table (irrespective of how it obtains those rows).
- It also differs slightly from an *index scan* in that it works with the "full row".  Whereas an *index scan* has less overall data to process, because it works with a subset of columns.

But the question is actually asking about difference between physical and logical IO.

> (from disk) or will the optimizer understand that it's faster too (if there is enough RAM to hold the result set)

---

Yes the query will do 2 table scans. That cannot be avoided:

- the server has to process the full set of prices twice.
- and it has to finish processing for AVG(PRICE) before it can start processing for the WHERE filter.

However, a "logical" table scan does not necessarily require reading the data from disk twice. If all the data is in memory, the server can perform the table scan in memory. So although the second stage of processing must still perform a table scan, it can be more efficient by avoiding secondary disk access.

Take a look at this question to see how to distinguish logical and physical IO on mysql:
[For a MySQL query, how do you determine physical and logical I/O?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171/10426)

---

I'll add that in theory a server could choose to keep only the Price column in memory on the first pass. In which case it wouldn't need be perform a "full table scan" on the second pass.
However this is unlikely in practice as there's a benefit to keep all the data in memory for other future queries ... *whatever columns they may wish to process*.

Comment: With `INDEX(p_price)`, the first scan would be an "index scan".

Comment: @RickJames The question explicitly states: "The table has no indexes". ***If there were such an index***, then yes; it would scan the index on the first pass, and might (depending on other factors) seek into the index on the second pass.

Comment: @CraigYoung i get your point about the flaw in the question and see that i was not clear about what i meant. sorry. table scan had the meaning(at least in my mind) "read from disk" and not "iterate table rows". thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Kapalua I actually thought it was clear what you meant (based on the part of your question I quoted) and realised where your confusion was. (Unfortunately some people probably focused too much on the "table scan" element and missed the point of your question. I decided to add the clarification about how your question was flawed later, because I figure a better understanding of terminology will make it easier to discuss/understand related topics in future.

Answer (score 2):

Re your comment:

> my assumption, when looking at the query, is than an optimizer should/would be able to determine that "this query reads the same data twice, after the first read i will put it into memory(if there is space) and use the in-memory data for the next part of the query, instead of asking the disk for it twice"

Well, at least in MySQL's InnoDB engine, something sort of like this happens. InnoDB can't really read pages directly from disk. It load every requested page into RAM before doing data operations on it. The RAM is a preallocated area called the [InnoDB buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html). This stores byte-for-byte copies of the pages from the on-disk tablespace, plus some metadata about them.

After reading a page, the buffer pool has no immediate need to evict it from RAM, unless other pages are requested and there's no space left in the buffer pool for them. So subsequent requests for the same pages may find the pages already residing in RAM. The more this happens, the better your performance overall.

You might have more data pages in your `product` table than can fit in your buffer pool. During a table-scan, InnoDB will evict pages as needed to load the remaining set of pages for the table. If you have a table that is many times larger than your buffer pool, you can imagine that this results in quite a bit of "churn" as pages come in and out. If you can afford it, allocating more RAM to the buffer pool is an good way to improve performance.

All these facts about the buffer pool don't change the fact that your query will perform two table-scans. It is true that it will be faster to read the pages from the buffer pool than reading pages from disk. You can experiment:

- Shutdown your MySQL Server and start it back up again. The buffer pool should be empty at this point (unless you are using the feature to [save the buffer pool on shutdown](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-preload-buffer-pool.html)).
- Run your query. It might take many seconds, because each page requested has to be read from disk before it can be used.
- Run the same query again. It's faster! I've seen cases where this difference makes the performance about 4x faster in tests. I understand that RAM is typically thousands of times faster than disk, but I/O speed is not the only code running. Also it depends on what other requests are occupying the disk bandwidth, and other factors.

The difference between disk speed and RAM speed is (more or less) an arithmetic factor. No matter how large your dataset, the speed difference gives the same advantage.

**Indexes are much more important,** because they turn a linear search O(n) into a B-tree search O(log<sub>2</sub>n). As your dataset gets larger, the advantage of this becomes more dramatic. This is why there is so much emphasis on [analyzing complexity of algorithms in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms).

Comment: (My Rule of Thumb has long been 10x faster when things are cached, but that may be rooted in HDD technology; perhaps 4x is better for SSDs.)

Comment: Yeah, too many variables related to hardware platform, data size, concurrent load, etc. Hard to make a general rule.

Comment: There's another important benefit of using indexes over and above the orders of complexity. If indexes can be used to find data efficiently, then less data is loaded into the buffer pool. I.e. you're only loading the data you actually use. Without indexes, your queries load entire tables into the buffer pool even if only a fraction of the data is needed. This fills the buffer pool and results in churning much sooner than you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain how you could do this with only one table scan.  It is not obvious.

The use of the `AVG()` function would typically result in two full scans.  If you have an index, then one or both scans might use the index.

Comment: my assumption, when looking at the query, is than an optimizer should/would be able to determine that "this query reads the same data twice, after the first read i will put it into memory(if there is space) and use the in-memory data for the next part of the query, instead of asking the disk for it twice"

Comment: @MHellenS -- That is still a "scan".  Caching does not avoid the scan, it avoids the I/O.